# Not able to create second geth node on the same machine

Tags: go-ethereum

I am trying to add a peer Geth node on the same machine using the link
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Setting-up-private-network-or-local-cluster
However, getting chainId which is wrong.

I have the following folder structure:

1. Blockchain

   - datadirone
   - datadirtwo
   - logs
   - myGenesis.json

myGenesis.json has following code:

```
{
  "config": {
  "chainId": 192,
  "homesteadBlock": 0,
  "eip155Block": 0,
  "eip158Block": 0,
  "byzantiumBlock": 0
},
"difficulty": "400",
"gasLimit": "2000000",
"alloc": {
    "<account>":{
         "balance":"1000"
 }
}}
```

I created my first node using command:

```
geth --datadir="./datadirone" -verbosity 6 --ipcdisable --port 30301 --rpcport 8101 console 2>> ./logs/01.log
```

In the response , I could see proper chainId as 192.

However, when I create the second geth node using command:

```
geth --datadir="./datadirtwo" -verbosity 6 --ipcdisable --port 30302 --rpcport 8102 console 2>> ./logs/02.log
```

It starts but with wrong chainid as 1.

What am I missing ?

Comment: how did you get chainid of the second node?

Comment: After the node starts, have diverted all logs to a file and I see this line there, which shows the chainId                                                                                                            `Persisted trie from memory database      nodes=12356 size=1.88mB time=84.315382ms gcnodes=0 gcsize=0.00B gctime=0s livenodes=1 livesize=0.00B
INFO [01-31|15:27:45.550] Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID: 1 Homestead: 1150000 DAO: 1920000 DAOSupport: true EIP150: 2463000 EIP155: 2675000 EIP158: 2675000 Byzantium: 4370000 Constantinople: <nil> Engine: ethash}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you run `geth --datadir="$DATADIR_PATH" init genesis.json` on both nodes?
And also try to put `--networkid 192` on the start command

Comment: It solved my problem. Thanks @waytosay 1. I had not run init genesis.json. So, first ran it. 2. Then added networkId . I got the same chainId.